# Easy way to copy file with package folders to another destination

Tags: java, deployment, patch

I have a Java class `x.java` and its compiled  representation `x.class` in a class path. I want to select `x.java` in my IDE view, press button 'Create Patch' and find
in selected folder all packages as folders and `x.class`.

For example if package is `com.x.y` I will find folders com,x,y and in folder y I will find `x.class`.

Is there any plugins/tools to do something like this?

Comment: Many IDEs already produce their compiled class files in this fashion. Eclipse certainly builds output directories in a structure that matches the package representation. Is your issue that you want to specifically produce only the `.class` file for the source files you select?

Comment: What do you mean by "create patch"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I use Intelij Idea And It produces a lot of  .class after project compile. All I want is to copy choosen .class files to directory with the same hierarchy as in directory where it was originaly stored by ide. The point is to create a patch for the appserver, that has such requrements for patches(.class must be stored in hierarchy of folders reflecting package)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such plugin; some plugins (like the Web Tools Project) can update web projects by copying only modified files but it's kind of a special case and there are existing tools which already solve this problem for the rest.

Try `rsync` ([docs](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html)), for example, or [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). They will find all changes for you (so no need to select or remember anything) and transfer them in an efficient way.